# Gparted cannot unmount USB

Tags: usb, mount, gparted

I recently bought a new USB, anyway when first plug it in i get this error.

[image]

Which is clearly wrong as this comp has never seen this USB before. And it does end up mounting anyway.

It shows up in gparted as dev/sdc but when i type in "df" into terminal it says its sdc1?  When i try to unmount with gparted it does nothing.

With the command

```
sudo umount -v /media/will/2086-84A4
```

which returns

```
/dev/sdc1 has been unmounted
```

but then it proceeds to mount anyway.

when i unmount using nautilus is disappears from gparted and "df" return.

Any ideas or similar threads (cant find anything similar?)

Thanks to anyone helping out a novice.

Comment: Look inside `/etc/fstab`. There should be a line that force your computer to mount the usb. Just comment out the line and restart the computer.